# Can I Zip a folder in hosting space using SSH?

Tags: javascript, php, ssh, server, hosting

Can I Zip a folder in hosting space using SSH and some codes ?

It's for clients so I can't tell them to use public keys/ putty/ commands/ ftp, I want to give them a url e.g http://yourdomain.com/createbackup, so that entire folder will be zipped and will be downloaded.

Thanks, any help/ guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read carefully this command line which will run over linux same as like putty in backend

```
<?php
    
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    
    
    $create_zip = shell_exec('sudo zip -r backup.zip FolderName');
    
   //backup.zip is your file , apply check this file does exit or not
   $zip_file='backup.zip';
    if(file_exists($zip_file)):
    
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($zip_file).'"');
            header("Content-length: " . filesize($zip_file));
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: 0");
    
        ob_clean();
            flush();
    
        readfile($zip_file);
    
        unlink($zip_file);
    
    else:
    echo 'Somthing went wrong please try again;'
```

Comment: Will this create a zip too?

Comment: yes as you create through SSH , first sheel_exec command will do same , you can modify command as per your requirement and always check your location

Comment: Your welcome, if you still face issue please let me know

Answer (score 1):

With php. You can use [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
and [tar command](https://www.tecmint.com/18-tar-command-examples-in-linux/) in linux.
Example:

```
exec(tar -cvf sampleArchive.tar /home/sampleArchive);
```